# Adding user interface in batch programme

Tags: batch-file, user-interface, wifimanager, wifi

I have this code.

```
    @ECHO OFF
    :Values
    SET strSSID=
    SET strPWD=
    ECHO Please enter the ssid:
    SET /p strSSID=SSID: 
    ECHO.
    ECHO Please enter the password:
    SET /p strPWD=Password: 

    IF ".%strSSID%"=="." GOTO :TryAgain
    IF ".%strPWD%"=="." GOTO :TryAgain

    CALL :HostedNW "%strSSID%" "%strPWD%"
    pause
    GOTO :EOF
   :HostedNW
   ECHO
   C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe wlan set hostednetwor mode=allow ssid="%~1" key="%~2" keyUsage=persistent
   SET strSSID=
   SET strPWD=
   GOTO :EOF
   :TryAgain
   CLS
   ECHO.
  ECHO One or more inputs weren't correct.
  ECHO Please try again.
  ECHO.
  GOTO :Values
```

In which I have taken the proper inputs from user as SSID and PASSWORD, Now I have second code as:

```
    C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe wlan start hostednetwork
```

This code will turn ON the WiFi, and another code which is :

```
    C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe wlan stop hostednetwork
```

This code will turn OFF the WiFi.
Now I want all these codes in one codding format and wanted to display a proper user interface in which:
first clickable button will show "Configure WiFi"
second clickable button will show "Turn ON"
third clickable button will show "Turn Off"
fourth clickable button will exit the user interface.

and the respective buttons will run the respective code designed for it in same manner as mentioned above.
If possible suggest me how to improve the user interface of this file.
Please Help Me With This Problem . . .

Comment: Batch is text-based, which means that it is incapable of making anything clickable.

Comment: Ok I got it. But can it is possible to make an file in which 4 Options are shown and asks for particular

Comment: You can do text-based menus, sure. You can use the `choice` command if you're running a system later than XP, or `set /p` and some if statements otherwise.

Comment: Thanks sir for you help but sir if possible can you tell me in detail how to do it or if possible can you made it in the programme ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is something along the lines of what you're looking for.

```
@echo off

:mainmenu
cls
echo *********************
echo *     WiFi Menu     *
echo *********************
echo * 1. Configure WiFi *
echo * 2. Enable WiFi    *
echo * 3. Disable WiFi   *
echo * 4. Quit           *
echo *********************
choice /C:1234 >nul

if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto config
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto enable
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto disable
if %errorlevel% equ 4 goto quit

:quit
exit /b

:config
set "strSSID="
set "strPWD="

:: Enter the SSID and password
set /p "strSSID=Please enter the SSID: "
set /p "strpwd=Please enter the password: "

:: Ensure that the user input is not empty
if "%strSSID%"=="" goto tryagain
if "%strPWD%"=="" goto tryagain

:: Affiliate the SSID with the password
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="%strSSID%" key="%strPWD%" keyUsage=persistent
echo Wifi configured
pause
goto mainmenu

:: Inform the user that required information was not supplied
:tryagain
cls
echo.
echo Please input both an SSID and password.
echo.
goto config

:: Activate the WiFi
:enable
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
echo WiFi enabled
pause
goto mainmenu

:: Disable the WiFi
:disable
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
echo WiFi disabled
pause
goto mainmenu
```

Comment: Thanks Sir For Your Valuable Help.